# Python, count string starts with 'r', it is always 1 no matter how many there are

Tags: python, string

I need to count files which starts with "RE", turns out no matter how many I have, it is always 1 as result.

I simplified my code a bit. Seems 'r' is always excluded from the 2nd occurence onward.

I'm not sure but I think it is something related to regular expression, which I don't have any knowledge about.

Below is the simplified code to recreate the same issue.

```py
count = 0
to_be_counted = ['r', 'l', 'r', 'l', 'r', 'l']
for each in to_be_counted:
    if each == 'r':
        count =+ 1
print(count)
```

`3` is expected, but the output is `1`.

Comment: `=+` is backward.

Answer (score 3):

```
count =+ 1
```

That line is setting `count` to positive one.

You want `+=` instead, which will increment the `count` variable by one.

Comment: Ah that's why it's always 1. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Doing `count =+ 1` is wrong, but if you change the `=+` to `+=`, or even just change the whole `count =+ 1` to `count = count + 1` it'll work

`count =+ 1` doesn't work, in my opinion, it's because with this statement (like @Pikamander2 mentioned in his answer) count is being assigned the value of `+1`.